# Receiving notifications from Facebook using facebook sdk for android?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, notifications

I'm creating an android application in which i want to get Facebook notifications of logged-in user.I tried a code for this.My questions are

1.How to set MANAGE_NOTIFICATIONS permission?
2.Not sure whether my code is correct

Here is my code for getting notifications.
Any help will be appreciated...

```
public void getNotification() 
    {
        mAsyncRunner.request("me/notifications", new RequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                Log.d("Notifications", response);
                String json = response;
                try {
                    // Facebook Profile JSON data
                    JSONObject notifications = new JSONObject(json);

                    // getting name of the user
                     name = notifications.getString("name");

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Notifications..."+name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    });


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                    Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                    Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: need to change code like this here. that i was talking about using of session class.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24117785/the-user-hasnt-authorized-the-application-to-perform-this-action-android-facebo

Answer (score 0):

I found another way. I will post it in case somebody finds it helpful

```
private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
if (state.isOpened()) {
    InboxMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    new Request(session,"/me/notifications", null,HttpMethod.GET,new Request.Callback() {

                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    GraphObject object = response.getGraphObject();
                        if (object != null) {
                            InboxMessage.setText(object.getProperty("data").toString());
                        } else {
                            InboxMessage.setText("Notifications returns null");
                        }
                }
            }
        ).executeAsync();
} else {
    InboxMessage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
}
}
```