# The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action android facebook SDK (#200)

Tags: android, facebook

I am posting on my wall in facebook sdk 3.6 android but I am getting error:

{HttpStatus: 403, errorCode: 200, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action}

I tried all the ways what i found here. But still i am getting same error.

```
public class FacebookHelper implements OnFacebookPostClickListener {

private static final String KEY_MESSAGE = "message";
private static final String KEY_LINK = "link";
private static final String KEY_MY_WALL = "me/feed";
private Activity mActivity;
private Resources mResources;
private String mMessage;
private String mShareLink;
private WWFFacebookDialog mFacebookDialog;
private String mPortraitKey;

/**
 *  Class to provide asynchronous notification of Session state changes.
 * 
 */
private Session.StatusCallback mStatusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {

    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (session.isOpened() || FacebookSessionHelper.hasPublishPermission()) {
            checkSessionState(session, state, exception);
        } else if (session.isOpened()) {
                            OpenRequest open = new OpenRequest(mActivity).setCallback(this);
            List<String> permission = new ArrayList<String>();
            permission.add(FacebookSessionHelper.PUBLISH_ACTION_PERMISSION);
            open.setPermissions(permission);
            session.openForPublish(open);

        }
    }
};

public FacebookHelper(Activity activity) {
    mActivity = activity;
    mResources = mActivity.getResources();
}

/**
 * Method to set result after Facebook login.
 * 
 * @param requestCode The integer request code originally supplied to startActivityForResult(), allowing you to identify who this result came from.
 * @param resultCode The integer result code returned by the child activity through its setResult().
 * @param data An Intent, which can return result data to the caller (various data can be attached to Intent "extras").
 */
public void setFacebookLoginResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    FacebookSessionHelper.saveOnActivityResult(mActivity, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

/**
 * Method to share with Facebook.
 * 
 * @param message Message to share.
 * @param shareLink Link to share.
 */
public void shareWithFacebook(String message, String shareLink, String portraitKey) {
    mMessage = message;
    mShareLink = shareLink;
    mPortraitKey = portraitKey;
    if (FacebookSessionHelper.isOpened() || FacebookSessionHelper.hasPublishPermission()) {
        showFacebookAlert();
    } else {
        loginToFacebook();
    }
}

/**
 * Method to login to Facebook.
 */
private void loginToFacebook() {
    Session session = FacebookSessionHelper.getActiveSession(mActivity);

    if (!session.isOpened() && !session.isClosed()) {
        session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(mActivity).setCallback(mStatusCallback));
    } else {
        Session.openActiveSession(mActivity, true, mStatusCallback);
    }
}

/**
 * Method to check Facebook session state.
 * 
 * @param session Facebook session.
 * @param state the state of a Session.
 * @param exception  
 */
private void checkSessionState(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    if (exception instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException ||
            exception instanceof FacebookAuthorizationException) {
        AppUtils.showAlert(mActivity, mResources.getString(R.string.cancelled), 
                mResources.getString(R.string.permission_not_granted));
    } else if (state == SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED) {
        AppUtils.showAlert(mActivity, mResources.getString(R.string.cancelled), 
                mResources.getString(R.string.session_busy));
    } else {
        showFacebookAlert();
    }
}

/**
 * Method to show alert to display the user message to post.
 */
private void showFacebookAlert() { 
    mFacebookDialog = new WWFFacebookDialog(mActivity, mMessage, this);
    mFacebookDialog.show();
}

/**
 * Method to post to Facebok wall.
 */
private void postToFacebookWall(String message) {
    Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
    postParams.putString(KEY_MESSAGE, message);
    postParams.putString(KEY_LINK, mShareLink);
    Request.Callback callback= new Request.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
            if (error != null) {
                Log.d("TAG", ">>>>Error: " + error.toString());

                AppUtils.showToastMessage(mActivity, error.getErrorMessage());
            } else {
                AppUtils.showToastMessage(mActivity, mResources.getString(R.string.posted_successfully));
                AppUtils.setSharedOrigami(mActivity, mPortraitKey);
            }

            mFacebookDialog.dismiss();
        }
    };

    Request request = new Request(FacebookSessionHelper.getActiveSession(mActivity), 
            KEY_MY_WALL, postParams, HttpMethod.POST, callback);

    RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
    task.execute();
}

@Override
public void onFacebookPostClick(String message) {
    postToFacebookWall(message);
}
```

}

```
public class FacebookSessionHelper {

private static Session mSession;
public static final String PUBLISH_ACTION_PERMISSION = "publish_actions";
public static final String LIKE_PERMISSION = "user_likes";


/**
 * Returns the session if active, else returns null
 * @param context - in which context to be used
 * @return active session
 */
public static Session getActiveSession(Context context) {
    mSession = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (mSession == null) {
        mSession = new Session(context);
        Session.setActiveSession(mSession);
    }

    return mSession;
}

/**
 * Restores the session from bundle if app is destroyed
 *  if its running in background to recover the memory
 * @param context - in which context to be used
 * @para cachingStrategy the TokenCachingStrategy to use to load and store the token. If this is null, a default 
 token cachingStrategy that stores data in SharedPreferences will be used
 * @param statusCallback - status call back of session to be called 
 * upon open, closed states.
 * @param savedInstanceState - bundle info of activity
 */
public static void restoreSessionFromBundle(Activity context, TokenCachingStrategy cachingStrategy, StatusCallback statusCallback, Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
    mSession = Session.restoreSession(context, cachingStrategy, statusCallback , savedInstanceState);
}

/**
 * Opens the session in read mode which is not yet open, but has cached token
 * @param context - in which context to be used
 * @param statusCallback - - status call back of session to be called 
 * upon open, closed states.
 */
public static void openSession(Activity context, StatusCallback statusCallback) {
    if ((mSession != null) && (mSession.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED))) {
        mSession.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(context).setCallback(statusCallback));
    }
}

/**
 * Adds the callback to the session
 * @param statusCallback - status call back of session to be called 
 * upon open, closed states.
 */
public static void addCallback(StatusCallback statusCallback) {
    if (mSession != null) {
        mSession.addCallback(statusCallback);
    }
}

/**
 * Removes the callback from session
 * @param statusCallback - status call back of session to be called 
 * upon open, closed states.
 */
public static void removeCallback(StatusCallback statusCallback) {
    if (mSession != null) {
        mSession.removeCallback(statusCallback);
    }
}

/**
 * Save the session into bundle for recovering data when app runs in low memory 
 * @param outState - bundle info
 */
public static void saveSessionIntoBundle(Bundle outState) {
    if (mSession != null) {
        Session.saveSession(mSession, outState);
    }
}

/**
 * Save activity result into session.
 * 
 * @param activity activity context.
 * @param requestCode The integer request code originally supplied to startActivityForResult(), allowing you to identify who this result came from.
 * @param resultCode The integer result code returned by the child activity through its setResult().
 * @param data An Intent, which can return result data to the caller (various data can be attached to Intent "extras").
 */
public static void saveOnActivityResult(Activity activity, int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (mSession != null) {
        mSession.onActivityResult(activity, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}

/**
 * Says whether session is opened or not
 * @return true if session is opened, else false
 */
public static boolean isOpened() {
    boolean isOpened = false;
    if (mSession != null) {
        isOpened = mSession.isOpened();
    }

    return isOpened;
}

/**
 * Says whether current session has publish permission
 * @return true if it has publish permission, else false
 */
public static boolean hasPublishPermission() {

    return ((mSession != null) &&
            (mSession.getPermissions().contains(PUBLISH_ACTION_PERMISSION)));
}

/**
 * Says whether current session has publish permission
 * @return true if it has publish permission, else false
 */
public static boolean hasLikePermission() {

    return ((mSession != null) && 
            (mSession.getPermissions().contains(LIKE_PERMISSION)) &&
            hasPublishPermission());
}

/**
 * Requests for new publish permission
 * @param context - in which activity permission to be granted
 */
public static void requestNewPublishPermission(Activity context) {
    if (mSession != null) {
        mSession.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(context, PUBLISH_ACTION_PERMISSION, LIKE_PERMISSION));
    }
}

/**
 * Close the session and clear the token cache, nullifies the session object
 */
public static void closeSession() {
    if (mSession != null) {
        mSession.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
        mSession = null;
    }
}
```

}

status_update

Comment: check your permission array may be you are trying to do something that you have not asked in your permission array

Comment: I am just posting the text and link.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make the facebook to visible all,

**follow the steps,**

open your app of facebook and click status and review tab,
  check the yes to **Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?**

Comment: Hello. i am also getting the same issue. have you solved it? can you please help me? i tried google too but not able to fix it. i think something is going wrong with my facebook app configuration.